# In Python CSV module, how many rows does csv.Sniffer().has_header() require for accuracy?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Python's CSV module has a really handy [`csv.Sniffer().has_header()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer.has_header).

I can't figure out how many rows it needs in order to accurately determine whether the file has a header.

Will it generally work on CSVs with two rows, or three rows, or do I need more like five-ten rows for it to be accurate?

For context, here's my function--you can see I've got a check that says "don't allow sniffing the header if file has less than X rows" and currently I've got X set at 3, not sure if I need to be higher or can even set it at 2.

```
import csv

# input_file_has_header can be True, False, or 'Auto' if unsure. 
# input_file_has_header must be specified when file has less than 3 rows 
# because CSV's with two rows sometimes have a header and sometimes don't
# and I don't understand the magic underlying the csv.Sniffer().has_header() method

def csv_to_object_dict(input_csv, input_file_has_header='Auto', object_id_column=0, header_keys=[]):
    with open(input_csv,'rU') as object_file:
        object_reader = csv.reader(object_file)
        if input_file_has_header == 'Auto':
             while row_count < 5:
                for row in object_reader:
                    row_count += 1
        if input_file_has_header == True or (input_file_has_header == 'Auto' and csv.Sniffer().has_header(object_file.read(2048)) == True and row_count > 3): 
            next(object_reader, header_keys) #not sure this is correct
            print 'printing header keys ', header_keys # debug            
            assert header_keys != [], "File %s appears to have a header row, but there was a problem parsing it because header_keys remains empty" % input_csv      
        for row in object_reader:
            print 'printing new row ', row #debug
            if object_id_column not in object_dict:
                    object_dict[object_id_column] = {}
            for key in header_keys:            
                object_dict[object_id_column][key]= #value in the row that matches the key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, dive into the source:

```
def has_header(self, sample):
    # Creates a dictionary of types of data in each column. If any
    # column is of a single type (say, integers), *except* for the first
    # row, then the first row is presumed to be labels. If the type
    # can't be determined, it is assumed to be a string in which case
    # the length of the string is the determining factor: if all of the
    # rows except for the first are the same length, it's a header.
    # Finally, a 'vote' is taken at the end for each column, adding or
    # subtracting from the likelihood of the first row being a header.
```

And a quick perusal through the method shows that it doesn't try to enforce a minimum number of non-header rows; so, it will work on a file with only two rows, according to the above rules.

Comment: Yeah, except I have no idea where you pulled that from... How do I quickly find the underlying source code for a method like this in one of the standard Python libs?

Especially since the end of that comment in the source code says "a 'vote' is taken" which implies some magic... I'd love to look at how it calculates the "vote" but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: @JeffWidman lots of ways.  But try `import csv; print csv.__file__`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @roippi - I tried `nano [path_to_csv_module] ` and while nano obviously opened the right file, it's mostly weird characters. 

I'm looking for a more detailed answer here than just "look at the source". Certainly not an incorrect answer, but not that helpful when I don't know how to determine if the module is implemented in C or Python, and I don't know how to read C. I plan to learn these things, but don't have time now.

Hoping for a plain English answer that says "these are the edge cases you have to watch out for when trying to sniff files with less then 5 rows"

Comment: @JeffWidman you should open the `.py` version that is right next to the `.pyc` version that `__file__` (may) give.  `.pyc` is bytecode generated by the compiler.  Or just google `csv.py` and it is the [second hit](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/csv.py)

Comment: Thanks--that's helpful.